# Proof by Induction: Prove that $2^n > n^2$, for all natural numbers greater than or equal to $5$

Tags: inequality, induction

*Problem:* $2^n > n^2, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} , n \geq 5$

*Base:* $2^5 > 5^2$

*Induction Hypothesis:* Assume for $n = k \geq 5$ that $2^k>k^2$

*Inductive Step:*
$$2^k > k^2$$
$$2^k \times  2 > k^2 \times 2$$
$$2^{k+1} > 2k^2$$

From there I can finish the proof by asserting that $k^2 > 2k+1, \forall k \in \mathbb{N} , k \geq 3$.

Do I need to prove that $k^2 > 2k+1, \forall k \in \mathbb{N} , k \geq 3$. Or can I substitute it into my inequality?

Comment: You do need to prove this, just like you needed to prove that $2^k > k^2$, for $k \geq 5$. However, it is quite simple to do so. Hint: $(k-1)^2 > 2$ for $k \geq 3$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof by induction - Being stuck before being able to prove anything!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249743/proof-by-induction-being-stuck-before-being-able-to-prove-anything)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249743/proof-by-induction-being-stuck-before-being-able-to-prove-anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prove $k^2\color{blue}{\ge}2k+1$ for $k\ge\color{blue}{5}$ (unless your teacher thinks that's obvious enough to skip), although the stronger version you quoted is also correct. The proof does not, however, need induction. because it's equivalent to $(k-1)^2\ge2$.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how it can be simplified to $(k-1)^2 \geq 2$? I understand how you could simplify it to $(k-1)^2 \geq 0$ but not how it becomes 2

Comment: @HopelessSoul $k^2\ge2k+1$ rearranges to $(k-1)^2\ge2$ which, while not quite as trivial as $(k-1)^2\ge0$, follows if $k\ge3$ since then $(k-1)^2\ge2^2=4>2$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $$2^{k+1}=2^k+2^k> k^2 +2k+1$$

Comment: How would $2^{k+1} = 2^k + 2^k$? I thought $2^k + 2^k = 2^{2k}$

Comment: @HopelessSoul $2^{k+1}=2.2^k=2^k+2^k$

Comment: Generally I am using $$n>k \Rightarrow  2^{n} = 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} > 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-2} +1 > 2^{n-3} + 2^{n-3} + 2 > ... > 2^{n-k+1} + (k-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

You do need to prove it, as the onus is on you to demonstrate that you have understood the question.

My favourite method to prove this is to consider $2+\frac1k\le3$ for all $k\ge1$, and multiply through by $k$, then, as $k\ge3$, the RHS becomes $3k\le k^2$.

Answer (score 0):

*Still another way*:

If $n\ge 5$, we have
$$\Bigl(\dfrac{n+1}n\Bigr)^{\!2}=\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)^{\!2}<\Bigl(1+\dfrac15\Bigr)^{\!2}<2,$$
whence, by the inductive hypothesis,
$$2^{n+1}=2^n\cdot 2>n^2\cdot 2>n^2\Bigl(\dfrac{n+1}n\Bigr)^{\!2}=(n+1)^2.$$